# logging status not showing logged in with gmail android

Tags: android

I have integrated Gmail login in my app, I am able to fetch user email and name too, but button status not showing logged in.

**XML:**

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/sign_up_buttonId_withGooglePlus"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            />
```

**Code:**

```
onCreate(){

    signUpButton_withGooglePlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    signUpWithGooglePlus();

                }
            });
    }

public void signUpWithGooglePlus(){

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
//                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);

    }

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);



        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
            Log.v("ResDGooglePlus", result.toString());
            if(result.getSignInAccount().getEmail()!=null)
            firstNameEt.setText(result.getSignInAccount().getEmail());

        }

    }

private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {

        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
            Log.v("HandleSignInResultS:", acct.toString());
//            mStatusTextView.setText(getString(R.string.signed_in_fmt, acct.getDisplayName()));

            Toast.makeText(context_SignUpActivity,"Logged in as "+acct.getEmail(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//            Toast.makeText(context_SignUpActivity,acct.getEmail(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



        } else {

            // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.

        }
    }
```

I think I am missing some silly things in my code. How to solve this? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, button's width and height both should be `wrap_content`.

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
 android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Secondly, Google sign In builder methods should be written in onCreate() function rather than onClick event of the button.

```
void onCreate() { //function of your activity/fragment

GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestEmail()
        .build();

mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
        .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
        .build();

signUpButton_withGooglePlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
                    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);

                }
            });

}
```

This should work. Please refer to instructions in [official doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in).